# Network interface available only when running VM through VirtualBox, but not through Vagrant

Tags: networking, virtualbox, vagrant

Something strange here. I am using Vagrant and the centos/7 image to create some VMs for a few tests I want to run. Vagrant is using VirtualBox as the provider.

In my Vagrantfile, I set up a private network with an arbitrary IP.

If I `vagrant up`, and ping the VM on the arbitrary IP, the pings fail. `ip addr show` shows the proper interface, but with no IPv4 address.

If I start the VM through the VirtualBox UI, I can ping the VM just fine, and the IPv4 address shows up in `ip addr show`.

I have guest additions installed on the VM. I tried with 3 different CentOS 7 base boxes (jayunit100/centos7, bento/centos-7.2, and centos/7), but same results with each. When I used an Ubuntu box, everything worked as expected, and I could ping the box after loading it with `vagrant up`.

I'm running on OS X Sierra, my Vagrant version is 1.9.1 and my VirtualBox version is 5.1.10.

Anyone have any clues to share? Thanks!

*EDIT* below is one of the Vagranfiles I used, comments removed for brevity.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "bento/centos-7.2"

  # config.vm.box_check_update = false

  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080

  # NOTE: tried this with virtualbox__intnet: true as well, didn't help
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.101"

  # config.vm.network "public_network"

  # config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"

  # More settings below, but all commented out, so removed for brevity
end
```

Comment: Just tried this with a different box, same results.

Comment: [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1155262/edit) your question and include the Vagrantfile.

Comment: Used 3 different CentOS boxes, same result. However, no issues with Ubuntu.

Comment: Please note that no one asked you how many times you tried. If you think this information is vital (it's not, btw), include it in your question, not comments.

Comment: @techraf the Vagrantfile is the default result of `vagrant init box_name`, with the private network line uncommented. I can add the file, but considering the small change, I feel that would just be clutter?

Comment: I asked you to edit the question and include it, not to write stories about it. You wrote you "set up an arbitrary network", so it's **not** the default one. If you want help, you need to provide information.

Comment: @techraf unnecessarily rude in both your replies.

Comment: Rude because asking for information to help you, while you refuse. Interesting point of view.

Comment: @techraf Nobody's refusing, and you're still being rude. Please be civil, or, if you can't, leave this question for others who can. Hope your day gets better and you chill out a little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue. The solution for me was to not define a static ip address, but let one be determined by setting 'type: dhcp' (see: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/private_network.html). Via dhcp an ip address is selected out of a preset valid range (virtualbox issue?), which I guess does not include the 192..... anymore? Haven't tried it yet, but maybe setting the range via 'modifyvm' with directives from here http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#changenat can solve the issue also?

Comment: Using the modifyvm with natnet1 stuff seems to change the IP of the first interface. The 2nd interface, the one that would actually be exposed as the private interface, does not seem to be affected. Tried with natnet2, but that didn't seem to have an effect. That said, the dhcp solution does allow me to use private networks with CentOS.

Comment: Ideally, I could set the range for the second interface so I could use a single entry in the hosts file to mimic a DNS entry for the VM without having to modify it.

Comment: Is the natnet2 defined? Otherwise have a look here first to set a natnet network/inspect the settings: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-natnetwork. If that is set correctly, then via VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --<interface-name> "192.168/16" (see for details https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-natnetwork) it may work.